# Nodejs Test not erroring out inside Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jestjs, supertest

So I'm a bit new to nodejs and promise handling, and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Right now when I run this test I expect it to fail with the error message in `throw new Error` but instead the test passes and then just prints the error message `Invalid: XXXXXXX` as part of an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Here is what my test looks like. How can I make this test fail when `valid` is not `true`? This test is run with jest. I've attached a screenshot of the test passing (when it should fail).[image]

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { verifyJsonResponse } = require('../verifiers/verifiers');

const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
const assert = require('assert');

const baseURL = 'myAPIBaseUrl';
const endPointExtensions = ['myAPIExtension'];
const schema = require('./../pathToJsonSchema/schemaFile.json');

describe('runs remotely specified test cases', () => {
    it('should receive expected response for each parameter group', () => {
        request(baseURL).get(endPointExtensions[0]).then((res) => {
            const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
            const valid = validate(res.body);
            if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
            else throw new Error('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How does your test framework support asynchronous tests?

Comment: as Bergi mentioned that root cause is async flow: first your test is passed and only then promise is fullfilled(it does not matter if it's resolved or rejected for that time)

Comment: code looks like Jasmine-based. for Jasmine refer to https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: It's a new framework we just built so it doesn't currently support async testing. Would there be an easy way to implement it for this code or a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` appears, because promise rejection is not handled.

Jest inherently supports promises in specs. In order for asynchronous spec to make use of existing promise, it should be returned from the spec:

```
it('should receive expected response for each parameter group', () => {
    return request(baseURL).get(endPointExtensions[0]).then((res) => {
        const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
        const valid = validate(res.body);
        if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
        else throw new Error('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
    });
});
```

Or:

```
it('should receive expected response for each parameter group', async () => {
    const res = await request(baseURL).get(endPointExtensions[0]);
    const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
    const valid = validate(res.body);
    if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
    else throw new Error('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
});
```